# Covert from microsoft research kinect to new sdk

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

Microsoft.Reasearch.Kinect.Nui.Vector vector = new Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui.Vector();
I understand that the vector name has been removed from the new sdk, but what does the above line mean please? how can I implement it in the new sdk code